# Smooth shading on model causes weird artifacts

Tags: mesh, topology, shadows, polycount

[image: model with smooth shading enabled in object mode]
[image: one half of the model in edit mode (because the other half is a mirror modifier)]
it's more visible with matcap, it looks like it's all distorted metal hit with a hammer, but in edit mode the topology looks smooth for me.
i'm a beginner in modeling/blender, i've tried recalculating normals, adjusting various points, using some addons to "relax" the topology and smoothen it, nothings worked, adding a subsurface modifier set to 1 makes the effects disappear but then the model is too high-res for my low poly game, i want to keep it very performant.

[blend file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/u75s0eqc24dzu7f/SkinnedMeshRig.blend/file)

Comment: Have you baked normals from another mesh?

Comment: i'm not sure what baking normals mean, but this is an imported model that i modified, i'm just not sure where it went wrong, it didn't have this problem previously

Comment: Try to disable "autosmooth" (object data properties tab and normals section) and clear custom normals (object data properties tab and geometry data section)

Comment: oh wow that worked perfectly, i don't know what autosmooth did but it surely messed up the normals, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try to disable "autosmooth" (object data properties tab and normals section) and clear custom normals (object data properties tab and geometry data section)

Answered by lemon